# cvs checkout without knowing the repository location

Tags: cvs

I need to do CVS checkout of a project. I have the following info:
1. IP of the server
2. User/pass
3. Module Name.
4. Branch Name

What I don't have is the repository location, I tried /usr/local/cvs /usr/local/cvsroot, /user/local/CVSROOT, /usr/cvs, etc.

Is there a cvs command to get me the location of the repository folder?

Comment: There is no such command, but check the `CVSROOT` environment variable (`env | grep CVSROOT`). If not defned - search for `CVSROOT` folder over the whole system (`find / -type d -name CVSROOT`)

Comment: I don't have the user/pass of the server which contains the CVS Repository, otherwise, I would simply run any command I want using putty

Answer (score 1):

If client and server are CVSNT then you can use the following command to query for published repositories:

```
cvs info -r <server>
```

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>cvs info -r 172.30.1.52  Couldn't enumerate remote server. Server does not support enum protocol.

Comment: Do you know whether the server is running CVSNT? The enum-protocol is an optional component that can be deselected at installation time. If that's not the problem, then your server is probably not CVSNT but a regular, vanilla CVS.